# LWC Repeating Lighting Layout Items with for:each record set and on-click action not getting ID of item clicked

Tags: lightning-web-components, component, onclick

Primary goal:

- LWC on Campaign Lightning Page (done)
- Get list of Campaign Members from apex wire (done)
- Generate list of Campaign Members on left half of screen using lightning layout items (completed)
- When user clicks one of the people on the left, load a child component on the right side of the screen with that person's details (in progress / stuck)

When clicking on a campaign member (repeated item with for:each key), I can't seem to get the member or member id passed via event (on-click).

The console just shows undefined no matter what variety of target, currentTarget, dataset, detail, etc. I try to use. I've looked at tons of other articles and nothing seems to work.

Ultimately, I am trying to access the data ID so I can pass it to a child component using the event like this: (https://www.apexhours.com/events-in-lightning-web-components-lwc/)

```
export default class ParentComponent extends LightningElement {
handleChangeEvent(event){
    this.template.querySelector('c-child-Comp').changeMessage(event.target.value);
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<template for:each={campaignMembers} for:item="member">
    <lightning-layout-item key={member.id} data-item={member} size="12" padding="horizontal-small" flexibility="auto" class="slds-card_boundary slds-m-bottom_small member-card" onclick={handleMemberClick}>
        <lightning-card icon-name={member.Icon} hoverable>
            <h4 slot="title">{member.FirstName} {member.LastName}</h4>
            <lightning-badge slot="actions" label={member.Status}></lightning-badge>
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</template>
```

Here is my JS

```
handleMemberClick(event) {

    console.log(event.target.dataset.member);
    console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.member);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the property: `data-item={member}`, so to access it, it would be `event.currentTarget.dataset.item`. However, you should note that whatever you put into the attribute will have `toString()` called on it, so don't use the `member` itself, but instead, a unique value you can determine later, such as the record's Id (e.g. `data-member-id={member.Id}`), which you'd then find the appropriate record:

```
const member = this.campaignMembers.find((member) => member.Id === event.target.dataset.memberId)
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense now. Solved the problem. I appreciate it.